# Set raw value with Rails.cache.write

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, memcached

I'm trying to save entire response.body to memcached. I'm doing it like so:

```
Rails.cache.write(request.headers['HTTP_X_MEMCACHED_KEY'], response.body)
```

The problem is that it prepends some garbage to the value:

```
o: ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry  :@compressedF:@expires_in0:@created_atf1355928410.584484:@value"GsI";s<!DOCTYPE html>...
```

I tried to pass `:raw => true` to `Rails.cache.write`, but it returns false and doesn't put the value to memcached. I think it fails because response.body is not properly escaped.

I also tried this way:

```
Rails.cache.write(request.headers['HTTP_X_MEMCACHED_KEY'], Marshal.dump(response.body), :raw => true)
```

It works, but there's still some garbage in the value:

```
I"fD<!DOCTYPE html>...
```

How to put a clean value into memcached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems memcached was unable to cache data because of unescaped unicode characters in `response.body`.

Now I'm passing `response.body.bytes.to_a.map(&:chr).join` as the value, it works fine, but I'm still wondering if it is the best solution.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution? I want to get rid of those random values too.

Answer (score 0):

writing `response.body.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')` might be a solution

Comment: Please explain your answer.